# Can the Android native CardView be used in Xamarin Forms XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've messed around as best I can but I can't find a way to embed the native xamarin.android CardView control within xamarin.forms xaml.  Following is my code:

**my namespaces**

```
xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"    
xmlns:androidWidgetv7="clr-namespace:Android.Support.V7.Widget;assembly=Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView;targetPlatform=Android"
xmlns:androidLocal="clr-namespace:MyApp.Droid;assembly=MyApp.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
```

**My Xaml**

```
<androidWidgetv7:CardView x:Arguments="{x:Static androidLocal:MainActivity.Instance}" View.HorizontalOptions="Center" View.WidthRequest="600" View.HeightRequest="300">
    <androidWidget:TextView x:Arguments="{x:Static androidLocal:MainActivity.Instance}" Text="Simple Native Color Picker" TextSize="24" View.HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</androidWidgetv7:CardView>
```

**I get the following error**

```
Exception is: XamlParseException - Position 32:18. Can not set the content of androidWidgetv7:CardView as it doesn't have a ContentPropertyAttribute
```

There are zero examples on the web showing how to do this.  Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. but you can implement a similar version of it like how they did [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/card-view).

you can find alternative versions [here](http://hire-xamarin-developer.com/blog/card-view-in-xamarin-forms-xamarin-solution/) and [here](https://github.com/tiger4589/Xamarin.Forms-CardView).

Don't expect to get android animations/touch gestures here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="245dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:text="Basic CardView"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]